# Isn't it a subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a problem with the concept of subspace.

---

> Determine that following sets are subspaces of **$R^2$**.
>
> (1) $W = \{(a,b+1)|a,b \in R\}$
>
> (2) $V = \{(a+2b,b+1)|a,b \in R\}$

---

I know $W$ and $V$ are two dimensional  planes so that $W$ and $V$ might be subspaces of **$R^2$**.

But I have understood the definition of subspace such that a subset of a vector space that is closed under vector addition and scalar multiplication.
From above definition, I determine that $W$ of (1) is a subspace of $R^2$ but $V$ of (2) isn't.

(1) For $v=(a,b+1), u=(c,d+1), v+u=(a+c,(b+d+1)+1)$.
And for $k \in R: kv=(ka,(kb+k-1)+1)$.
So $W$ is a subspace of $R^2$.

(2) For $v=(a+2b,b+1), u=(c+2d,d+1),
v+u=((a+c)+2(b+d),(b+d)+2)$.
Because the form of $v+u$ is not $(x+2y,y+1)$ but $(x+2y,y+2)$, $V$ is not a subspace of $R^2$.

My answer (1) is correct but (2) is not correct.
Why?
I don't know where I am wrong.
Please help me!

Comment: let y = b+d+1, then x = a+c-2

Answer (score 2):

For the second, your argument does not hold: that is, $u+v$ **is** in $V$. Take $x = a+c-2$ and $y=b+d+1$. Then $$
x+2y = a+c-2 + 2(b+d+1) = (a+c)+2(b+d), \qquad y+1 = (b+d)+2
$$
i.e. $u+v=(x+2y,y+1)\in V$.

---

To find $x,y$ above, I basically solved the equations
$$\begin{align}
x + 2y &= (a+c)+2(b+d) \\
y+1 &= (b+d)+2
\end{align}$$
and found that the system *does* have a solution.

Comment: Aha! Thank you. It was a simple problem!